# CPF único mas com blank=True

Tags: django

Se eu defino

```
cpf = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

Acontece que se eu deixo um registro com o valor nulo, quando eu tento salvar um segundo registro, ele acusa valor duplicado.

Como contornar essa situação?

Comment: Qual SGBD está usando?

Comment: @Math estou usando SQlite em dev e usarei PostgreSql em produção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você definir `unique=True` significa que você não pode repetir nenhum valor, <strike>até mesmo `NULL`</strike>. A solução para este problema é fazer uma verificação antes de salvar, se houver repetidos retorna erro para o usuários.

No `forms.py` você pode pode fazer uma verificação da seguinte maneira:

```
class SeuModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model = SeuModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SeuModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'instance' in kwargs:
            self.id = kwargs['instance'].id
        else:
            self.id = None

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(SeuModelForm, self).clean()
        cpf = cleaned_data.get('cpf')
        if cpf:
            try:
                SeuModel.objects.exclude(id=self.id).get(cpf=cpf)
            except (SeuModel.DoesNotExist):
                pass
            else:
                self.add_error('cpf', u'Este CPF já foi cadastrado')
```

### ATUALIZAÇÃO:

Após fazer uma pesquisa verifiquei que o problema não estava com o Django, sendo assim o banco aceita sim mais de um `NULL`. Para resolver este problema de forma mais simples, basta retorna `None` caso o campo não tenha sido preenchido.

```
class SeuModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model = SeuModel

    def clean_cpf(self):
        return self.cleaned_data['cpf'] or None
```

**Ou ainda melhor**, diretamente no método `save()` do model:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.cpf:
        self.cpf = None
    super(SeuModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: gostei de todas as soluções, utilizei a segunda. Mas quer dizer que a primeira verifica duplicidades e informa o usuário? Gostei.

Comment: Sim, a primeira verifica se tem algum cadastro usando o CPF informado, se houver ele retorna o erro.